# What was the <XMP> tag used for?

Tags: html, tags

Does anyone remember the `XMP` tag?

What was it used for and why was it deprecated?

Comment: Pretty sure it was used for annoying developers writing html parsers, considering this is valid (and used by google no less): `<xmp style="display:none"><!-- do not remove the plaintext nor xmp tags --><plaintext/><xmp>.</xmp>`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A quick Google search on W3C reveals that `XMP` was introduced for displaying **preformatted text** in HTML 3.2 and earlier. When W3C deprecated the `XMP` tag, it suggested using the `PRE` tag as a preferred alternative.

Update: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#xmp, http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.5.2.1

Comment: Actually they were already marked as "obsolete" in the HTML 3.0 reference. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/html3.dtd dating 1 August 1995. Which, incidentally, also quotes the exact reason why it was deprecated (this would be the answer to the OP's second question).

Comment: pre is not an alternative xmp quotes all contained text.  Great for debugging.  Not secure though.  Works everywhere AFAIK.

Comment: This page explains why `<xmp>` is not secure: https://html5sec.org/#134

Comment: @Julien It's not a secure way of concatenating user input into HTML (because it's still susceptible to XSS), but you shouldn't be doing it anyway. Afaik, using the tag _in general_ isn't a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 67):

`XMP` and `PRE` differ. Content within `PRE` tags is formatted as follows:

- Content is shown with a fixed font,
- All whitespace is preserved, and
- Each line break begins a new line.

If you want to include special characters such as `<`, `>` and `&` within `PRE` tags, they must be escaped so that they are not subject to special interpretation by the browser.

In contrast, content within `XMP` tags does *not* need to be escaped.

The only character sequence that cannot be included within `XMP` tags is the `XMP` end tag (`</XMP>`).

`XMP` is still supported by the browsers I have tested. You can try it with [xmp.html](http://dadinck.x10.mx/xmp.html). View the source to see the tags.

Comment: I have presented four ways of representing code. Textarea seems to be the winner. Here is my evaluation: http://dadinck.x10.mx/code_example.html

Comment: Security Note: XMP **is NOT** an XSS protection - its only purpose is when you are creating a **static** HTML page *by yourself* and you want to show some code without escaping it...

Comment: @dadinck, Your xml.html link links to *"The web hosting account associated with this website has been temporarily suspended! "*....

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry. That was only temporary. It is back again.

Comment: You forgot `<plaintext>`. Same advantages as `<xmp>` without any disadvantages _apart from_ that _everything_ (including any `</plaintext>`) after the tag will be printed verbatim, including `</body>` and `</html>`.

Comment: @Boldewyn `<plaintext>` is deprecated as well as `<xmp>` tag, thus is a no-go. Probably best alternative is `<textarea>` tag.

Comment: XMP is great for debugging raw html.

Answer (score 19):

XMP does some things that PRE does not support. I still depend on XMP, there is *no* substitute.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain *why* PRE is not a substitute for XMP. As it stands, this is not really an answer.

Comment: `<xmp>` ignores HTML tags and entities; `<pre>` doesn't.

Comment: How about `<textarea />` as a substitute?

Comment: How about using server-side-script escaping ? :P ..........................................................................................`<pre><?php echo htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES); ?></pre>`

Comment: Try debugging an XML output in browser using xmp and then pre. xmp will show the correct output.

Comment: Its been years, I'd forgotten about this post... but, XMP still comes up in some specialized cases where we've needed to present script markup as text (such as a code example) and then run that same script as code. Yes, its possible to do this in other ways now, but each has pros and cons. I guess I'm just giving a shout-out to the inventors of XMP, and a mild tsk tsk to the folks that wanted to take it away. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`<xmp>` is used with [strapdown.js](http://strapdownjs.com/) in formatting markdown notation. The name *strapdown* combining the terms *bootstrap* and *markdown*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Example</title>
  <xmp theme="united">
## Example

 - note one
 - note two
 - note three
  </xmp>
  <script src="http://strapdownjs.com/v/0.2/strapdown.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I still use the `xmp` tag for debugging `var_dump();` in PHP. I just can't remember to use the `pre` tag for some reason.

I think it doesn't really matter because if you really want to output text, you should use `textarea` with the `readonly` attribute.

Comment: It's very handy for this purpose. Since `var_dump()` doesn't return anything you need output buffer functions to HTML-encode its output. `<xmp>` is a quick alternative to writing a wrapper function and works everywhere.

Comment: Note that if there's any user input in the `var_dump()`, this method leaves you vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12235

For HTML5. it was, according to the HTML5 editor (comments 11 and 12), a very close call either way.

Answer (score 2):

I used `<textarea>`, which puts the html code into a neat box and clearly defines the code as different from the text before or after.

`<textarea><b>boldtext</b><textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

Still works to show raw html - if you use it in script, break the start tag.

```js
var stuff='<xmp'+'>this is shown as is<br/>hello</xmp>';
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML=stuff;
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
```