# getting linebreaks in <pre> tags

Tags: html

I'm creating comment fields which are based on user input into textarea. But when I use <pre> tags I can't tell it to wrap properly inside the comments view.

I'm not stuck on using <pre> tags if there is a better way of doing it. Only reason I chose to use it was to keep linebreaks and whitespaces added by user.

I noticed there is a property called "width" for <pre>, but W3 notes it as deprecated, and it only breaks after so and so many characters, which isn't ideal either. (It also doesn't work with IE at all.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The usual approach is to convert single newlines in the input to “<br />”. (Double-newlines would normally introduce a new “<p>” element.) This doesn't cover multiple-whitespace-runs though; if you need to preserve those, you could replace each two-space sequence with a space and a non-breaking space ('  ', ' \xA0', or ' &#160;' as a character reference).

There is a CSS way you can retain literal newlines and whitespaces but still wrap when the line length is too short:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

However this CSS 2.1 and CSS 3 property value is not supported cross-browser under its original name. Webkit (Safari, Chrome) picks it up; to get it to work under the other popular browsers, you have to add:

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

The ‘word-wrap’ is for IE, which as always has its own way of doing things.

Comment: The CSS styling worked. And since I'm in Norway, we've gotten on the anti-IE6 wave, so CSS2.1 and up is fully supported. Thanks, man!

Comment: Oh to be a web dev working in/for Norway with the anti-IE6. That must be good/case for fewer headaches.

Answer (score 21):

**The BEST Cross Browser Way** (chrome, internet explorer, Firefox). It worked for me to get line breaks and shows exact text:

CSS:

```
xmp{ white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word; }
```

HTML:

```
<xmp> your text or code </xmp>
```

Comment: XMP tag was **deprecated**. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545/what-was-the-xmp-tag-used-for for details. As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp, "Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

Comment: Thanks--`xmp` worked perfectly with a one-off task to generate a long list of sequential items, where no matter the browser rendering, `pre` was causing terrible problems with cut and paste from generated output.

Answer (score 6):

You could display the `pre` elements with `overflow:auto` like here on SO:

```
<pre style="overflow:auto">Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipisicingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.Duisauteiruredolorinreprehenderitinvoluptatevelitessecillumdoloreeufugiatnullapariatur.Excepteursintoccaecatcupidatatnonproident,suntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborum.</pre>
```

But the [`pre` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-PRE) is just intended for preformatted text like source code or plain text documents. Thus you should better add HTML line breaks ([`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-BR)) or even paragraphs ([`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P)).

Comment: The problem with using p-tags is that I loose the formatting the user might have added. And overflow scrolling is ugly :p

Comment: You may still want to have overflow, for those cases where someone types an annoyinglylongwordthatwontwrapnicelyandmessesupcertainkindsoflayout.

Answer (score 0):

FILENAME: whitespace.prewrap.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lorem Ipsum. Cicero.</title>
    <style>
        pre {
            white-space: pre-wrap; /* Allows for wrapping while preserving whitespace */
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum. Cicero.</h1>
    
<pre>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia odio vitae vestibulum. Donec in efficitur leo. Maecenas non diam cursus, imperdiet massa eget, pellentesque ipsum. Curabitur ut nibh et quam accumsan tempus at in urna. Sed at eleifend purus.

</pre>
</body>
</html>
```