# How to display a string with line spacings and indents retrieved from MySQL database using JSP?

Tags: html, mysql, database, jsp, web

I have a textbox where people are able to type in small code snippets. For example the user enter a code like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function $init() {return true;}
</script>

<body>
   <p checked class="title" id='title'>Title</p>
</body>
```

Then that is sent to the MySQL database as a string and is retrieved to another JSP page.The problem is that when retrieving, it sticks up together like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">function $init() {return true</script<body><p checked class="title" id='title'>Title</p></body>
```

**I want to know the easiest way to properly add line-spacings and indents to the string retrieved from database.My final output should be same as what the users enter at the first place.Help me?**

Comment: maybe you can check at [Retain newlines in HTML but wrap text: possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642140/retain-newlines-in-html-but-wrap-text-possible)

Comment: First confirm that the new lines and other whitespace is actually stored in the database by checking directly in MySQL. Next, if the characters are saved, how are you displaying the retrieved string?