# Line breaks disappear inside <pre>

Tags: html

Hi i'm using Google prettify plugin

I'm using the following code

```
<pre class="prettiprint">
Morris.Bar({
            element: 'barchart',
            axes: true,
            data: Object.keys(json.bar).map(function(key) {return json.bar[key]}),
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
            labels: ['Facebook', 'LinkedIn', 'Google+'],
            barColors: ['#707f9b', '#455064', '#242d3c']
        });
</pre>
```

But I get the following output

```
 Morris.Bar({ element: 'barchart', axes: true, data: Object.keys(json.bar).map(function(key) {return json.bar[key]}), xkey: 'x', ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'], labels: ['Facebook', 'LinkedIn', 'Google+'], barColors: ['#707f9b', '#455064', '#242d3c'] });
```

I need it like this,

```
Morris.Bar({
            element: 'barchart',
            axes: true,
            data: Object.keys(json.bar).map(function(key) {return json.bar[key]}),
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
            labels: ['Facebook', 'LinkedIn', 'Google+'],
            barColors: ['#707f9b', '#455064', '#242d3c']
        });
```

Comment: So, what styles have you applied to `pre` and to `.prettiprint`?

Comment: Previously I had prism syntax highlighter installed. I removed the css of prism and then the same code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638648/getting-linebreaks-in-pre-tags) it seems that applying some css rules to the `pre` will preserve newlines

```
pre{
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

EDIT: it works http://jsfiddle.net/rN763/

Comment: That answer is about how to get that effect *without* using `<pre>`. For `<pre>`, the standard behaviour (as you can see by removing the CSS from your example) is to preserve formatting, including newlines.