# line breaks in <textarea> and <pre>

Tags: html

This is a textarea. As you can see if the end is reached with letters it continues in a new line. Then i click uptade details, the letters are inserted into a database.

[image: ths]

Here at Info the text from the textarea is shown. It is a pre. But it doesnt make the line breaks.  How can i change the code so it gets shown in Info exactly how the text is formated in the textarea?

[image]

```
<textarea style=" width: 600px; max-width: 660px; height: 200px;  border: 1px solid; border-radius:4px;" placeholder="Beschreibe dich selbst genauer..." type="text" name="info">  </textarea>


<pre style="background-color: #93b9de54; max-width: 787px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">  </pre>
```

Comment: Try adding `white-space:normal` to the css for your `<pre>` tag

Comment: you can try to add cols and/or rows to your textarea . Try: cols='60'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting linebreaks in <pre> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638648/getting-linebreaks-in-pre-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `white-space` css attribute to `pre-wrap` for the `pre` tag  i.e

/*HTML*/

```
Content here
```

/* CSS */

```
pre { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

This will preserve line breaks and wrap text whenever necessary. You can read more  about the `white-space` css attribute [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)