# Can I use <pre> tag in any context I want linebreaks display?

Tags: html, line-breaks, pre

I'm looking up HTML text format on MDN and I came across with the example below:

```
<address>
  <p>
    Chris Mills<br />
    Manchester<br />
    The Grim North<br />
    UK
  </p>

  <ul>
    <li>Tel: 01234 567 890</li>
    <li>Email: me@grim-north.co.uk</li>
  </ul>
</address>
```

So, Instead of using the `<br/>` tag to separate the `<p>` content, can I use the `<pre>` tag? Further than that, can I use it in any context I want some linebreaks?

Comment: You could use [CSS white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) if you want to preserve line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS way you can retain literal newlines and whitespace.

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

[image]

For more information, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/638728/14145740).

Answer (score -1):

The `<pre>` tag cannot be used.

This is because `<pre>` defines if it is shown exactly like what is written in your source code, in monospace, and that it is pre-formatted text. Just like the comment above, you can use CSS white space.