# Why was the xmp HTML tag deprecated?

Tags: html, deprecated, w3c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [<XMP> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545/xmp-tag)

I know that it *is* deprecated of course, and I know how to work around it by using the `<pre>` tag, `<code>` tag, and escapes for `<>`.

My question is, **why** was it deprecated? The solution of having real code in an `<xmp>` tag seems so much more elegant than all this escaping we do nowadays, and yet, the one was neglected in favour of the other.

Any idea? Is there a reason for favouring `<pre>` with escapes over `<xmp>`?

Comment: I think it is going to be unlikely that you'll get an answer, given the decision was made in a closed environment over 15 years ago … it's off-topic anyway. Might be suitable for programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: It's not *just* deprecated, it was *completely removed* in the HTML5 (and I believe in HTML4) specification and should no longer be supported.

Comment: I understand both those points you're making, but on the decision being made in a closed circle: still they must've had their reasons, which were rooted in the way the element was being used (not by an enclosed group); and on the point of it being completely removed, I'm not trying to use it, I'm just trying to understand if there is anything wrong with the tag or the concept itself. Did it, for instance, pose security threats? (don't see how) Did people not want to have their code copy-pasted? That's still possible. The pre tag brings no advantages. Why remove something good?

Comment: @animuson - It's not completely removed from HTML5. It's listed as non-conforming here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features and more importantly, its parsing rules are described at http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tree-construction.html#parsing-main-inbody - search down from there for `A start tag whose tag name is "xmp"`

Comment: This was going to be an answer, but the question got closed. See http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12235

It was, according to the HTML5 editor (comments 11 and 12), a very close call either way.

Answer (score 6):

[This article](http://www.the-pope.com/listin.html) has a detailed decription on the depreciation of `xmp`.

tl; dr; to remove ambiguity in parsing html.

Answer (score 5):

The most compelling reason for me is that the use of the tag would make it impossible to consider html as a well-formed xml.

That is, the special meaning behind one tag that alters the way the document is processed is a bad precedent making it impossible to account for newer versions. For instance, there's no way you can skip unknown tag with its content if you can't tell when it's over without knowing this particular markup specs.

Comment: It is marked as deprecated in HTML 3.2. XML would not have been a consideration.

Comment: But the same reasons behind xml processing have already been there. (think SGML).

Comment: That actually makes sense, the only reason I've yet heard that does. Perhaps they wanted to kill it before people got too accustomed to it. Thank you, Michael.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a bit of elaboration, before I read your comment, but looks like you've got the idea, which is more general than detailed.

Comment: They left `<script>` and `<style>` alone though.

Comment: The content of these tags is specified and limited and even more limited in case of xml-conformant documents.

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#non-replaceable-character-data and the note after it. There's a difference between html and xml, but the effort is put into making comply with the other's standards. In particular, you can use external references for scripting and styling.

Comment: @Michael Krelin — It is specified and limited in exactly the same way as `xmp` in versions of HTML which have all three elements (i.e. HTML 3.2). Since the question is about why `xmp` was deprecated, there isn't a great deal of point in looking at changes to the specification that are taking place 15 years later.

Comment: Have you read my complete comment or am I asking for too much?

Comment: @Michael Krelin: I have. "The content of these tags is specified and limited" (in the same way as XMP). "even more limited in case of xml-conformant documents" (which is not relevant to the time that xmp was deprecated, and if it was, xmp could have been changed in the same way as script and style).

Comment: "In particular, you can use external references for scripting and styling", you *can*, but so what? The inline stuff still works.

Comment: html is *not* xml, but you *can* make html xml-compliant. Not with xmp, unless it's also externalized or conforms to xml syntax which is against its purpose.