# Display html code in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I've a contentEditable div, and I want to display the html script for the content of this div.
I'm using a [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com) alert to display my code, and the [Rainbow](http://craig.is/making/rainbows/) Plugin to highlight the syntax.

The is the code I'm using :

```
bootbox.alert('<pre><code data-language="html">'+ document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML + '</code></pre>');
```

I also used the `xmp` tag and this script:

```
<pre><![CDATA[
This is a demo, tags like <p> will
appear literally.
]]></pre>
```

as shown in this article : [How to display raw html code in PRE or something like it but without escaping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783708/how-to-display-raw-html-code-in-pre-or-something-like-it-but-without-escaping-it), but none of them has worked.

This is what I'm getting :

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use entities, like

```
var encodeHtmlEntity = function(str) {
  var buf = [];
  for (var i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    buf.unshift(['&#', str[i].charCodeAt(), ';'].join(''));
  }
  return buf.join('');
};
bootbox.alert('<pre><code data-language="html">'+ encodeHtmlEntity(document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML)) + '</code></pre>');
```

Comment: If you just concatenate the value of `createTextNode` you'll get `[object Text]`. You need to append the result to another element node. See this fiddle for working code: http://jsfiddle.net/4Mwxn/2/.