# Display doctype tag in html

Tags: html, xml, dom

I'm trying to display a few lines of xml in a manual to be copied and pasted. However, I cannot find a way to display

```
<!doctype login[ ...
```

and a few other xml tags. I cannot have extra characters or such, as a client will copy and paste the code.
Htmlentities doesn't solve the issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you could use the `xmp` tag

Comment: I would try to avoid the xmp tag as it has been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

Comment: No it is not *deprecated*, it is now *obsolete*. But, it will be continued to be supported by at least some time. Also, see this answer for more clarity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16785992/1355315 on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16783708/1355315

Comment: The mozilla link states "It has been deprecated since HTML3.2 and was not implemented in a consistent way. It was completely removed from the language in HTML5." That SO answer was written in May '13, the Mozilla documentation was updated in Nov '13.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found was to put parts of the tag in their own spans.

```
<span><</span><span>!</span>DOCTYPE <span>></span>
```

displays a doctype tag properly.

properly