# How to render only parts of a string as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to render a text as common HTML and parse occurrences of [code] tags that should be output unrendered - with the tags left untouched.

So input like this gets processed accordingly:

```
<p>render as HTML here</p>
[code]<p>keep tags visible here</p>[/code]
<p>more unescaped text</p>
```

I've regexed all code-tags but I have no idea how to properly set the text of the element afterwards. If I use jQuery's *text()* method nothing gets escaped, if I set it with the *html()* method everything gets rendered and I gained nothing. Can anybody give me a hint here?

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing gets escaped'?

Comment: The text gets displayed as is. I seem to have confused escaping with rendering.

Comment: You mean text displays with tags? right?

Comment: Oh so what you actually want to do is parse the data above (which you probably get from somewhere?) and then display it, but you want everything inside the [code] tags to be escaped so that you can see the actual html tags?

Comment: That's what I tried to express in my question, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `[code]` with `<xmp>` and `[/code]` with `</xmp>` using regex or alike, and then use the jQuery `html()` function.

Note that `<xmp>` is technically **deprecated** in HTML5, but it still seems to work in most browsers. For more information see [How to display raw html code in PRE or something like it but without escaping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783708/how-to-display-raw-html-code-in-pre-or-something-like-it-but-without-escaping-it).

Comment: That's it, thank you! Also thanks for the link, gave me some more insight.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `[code]` and `[/code]` tags by `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags respectively, and then replace the `<` within the `<pre>` tags by & lt;
A programmatic solution based on Javascript is as follows

```
function myfunction(){
  //the string 's' probably would be passed as a parameter

  var s = "<p>render as HTML here</p>\
  [code]<p>keep tags visible here</p>[/code]\
  <p>more unescaped text</p>";

  //keep everything before [code] as it is
  var pre = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('[code]'));

  //replace < within code-tags by &lt;
  pre += s.substring(s.indexOf('[code]'), s.indexOf('[/code]'))
           .replace(new RegExp('<', 'g'),'&lt;');

  //concatenate the remaining text
  pre += s.substring(s.indexOf('[/code]'), s.length);

  pre = pre.replace('[code]', '<pre>');
  pre = pre.replace('[/code]', '</pre>');

  //pre can be set as some element's innerHTML
  return pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would **NOT** recommend the accepted answer by [**Andreas**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636578/andreas) at all, because the `<xmp>` tag has been deprecated and browser support is **totally** unreliable.

It's much better to replace the `[code]` and `[/code]` tags by `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags respectively, as [**raghav710**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102114/raghav710) suggested.

He's also right about replacing the `<` character with `&lt;`, but that's actually not the only character you should replace. In fact, you should replace character that's a special character in HTML with corresponding HTML entities.

Here's how you replace a character with its corresponding HTML entity :

```
var chr = ['&#', chr.charCodeAt(), ';'].join('');
```

Comment: In addition to not using `<xmp>`, I would also avoid trying to escape the inserted text. Instead, I suggest using `node.textContent/jQuery.text`, to avoid XSS and for better performance with larger strings. `textContent` passes the text to be inserted directly to the browser, avoiding fiddly HTML entity escaping step.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `[code]...[/code]` with a placeholder element. And then `$.parseHTML()` the string with the placeholders. Then you can insert the code into the placeholder using `.text()`. The entire thing can then be inserted to the document (run below or [in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5mzfcgt/4/)).

```js
var str = "<div><b>parsed</b>[code]<b>not parsed</b>[/code]</div>";
var placeholder = "<div id='code-placeholder-1' style='background-color: gray'></div>";
var codepat = /\[code\](.*)\[\/code\]/;
var code = codepat.exec(str)[1];
var s = str.replace(codepat, placeholder);
s = $.parseHTML(s);
$(s).find("#code-placeholder-1").text(code);
$("#blah").html(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Text
<div id="blah">place holder</div>
Around
```

The code above will need some modifications if you have multiple `[code]` blocks, you will need to generate a unique placeholder id for each code block.

If you may be inserting untrusted structure code, would highly recommend using large random number for the placeholder id to prevent a malicious user from hijacking the placeholder id.