# How to prevent Javascript from parsing &quot; to "?

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

I've a strange problem, whenever I try to write a `&quot;` via javascript using the code below

```
function UpdateOutput(){
    var toWrite = "";
    toWrite += '&quot;' + value + '&quot;';
    element.innerHTML = toWrite;
}
```

The element displays

```
"value"
```

instead of

```
&quot;value&quot
```

There's a way to prevent this?

Comment: `&quot;` is interpreted as `"` when displayed as HTML which is what you tell the element to do when you set its HTML. Naively you could pre-replace `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display raw html code in PRE or something like it but without escaping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783708/how-to-display-raw-html-code-in-pre-or-something-like-it-but-without-escaping-it)

Comment: You can use `innerText` or [`insertAdjacentText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText)  instead of `innerHTML` to prevent html entities being decoded. Use insertAdjacentText in the case of prexisting elements in element

Comment: `innerText` worked like a charm for me, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `toWrite += '&amp;quot;' + value + '&amp;quot;';`