# HTML Code tags no execute

Tags: html, tags

How can I make code tags not execute as actual HTML tags and just display them on the page. It cannot be using the `&lt;` and `&gt;` function. For example how does this website do it inside of the code box?

How does this box not execute the code on the page?
Eg. `<img src="example.png" />` will not show.

How can I achieve this?
A little like shortcode API for WordPress but not on WordPress?

Comment: Using `&lt;` and `&gt;` is the only reliable, standard way to do this. Stackoverflow uses those entities and you can see them in the code section of your question by viewing the source of the page.

Comment: It's just the only way. I don't understand why "*It cannot be using the &lt; and &gt; function*"... View source of this page reveals: `<p><code>how does this box not execute the code on the page?
eg. &lt;img src="example.png" /&gt; will not show.</code></p>`

Comment: Okay I have viewed the source code of this page and I can see where you are coming from, thank you very much for your response though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use HTML Special Character Codes

I know you said you want to do this without them, but there's really no elegant way to do that. Nearly all server-side languages have some way to automatically convert HTML characters over.

PHP example:

```
<pre>
    <span id='code-span'>    
        <?= htmlspecialchars($code); ?>
    </span>
</pre>
```

If you don't have any server-side languages, you could do this with Javascript (jQuery):

```
var myCode = "<b>This is not bold</b>";
$('span#code-span').text(myCode);
```

Using `text` instead of `html` will cause tags to be rendered exposed instead of being executed.

Comment: `str_replace('<', '<img src="left-angle-bracket.png">', $code);` is the only alternative I can imagine.... and that is just a joke.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Not to mention requires server-side processing anyway.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Thanks, totally slipped my mind. :P

Comment: How could I do this with Javascript @LightningDust

Comment: @Harry Updated my answer with a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
 <xmp>insert code here</xmp>
```

Comment: Unless the code contains `</xmp>`...

Comment: This *may* work BUT `<xmp>` is deprecated since HTML 4.0. Also, not all browsers support it.

Comment: The `<xmp>` tag is for xml documents not html documents, sorry!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545/what-was-the-xmp-tag-used-for

Comment: <pre>
  <code> stuff stuff stuff stuff</code>
</pre>

Comment: @LightningDust - XMP has been deprecated since HTML 2.0

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer to your question, but rather an alternative (because there is no way except using the obsolete [`xmp` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete) to do what you're asking). You could use a [`textarea`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/textarea.html#textarea) to display arbitrary code. Just:

```
<textarea>Your HTML markup</textarea>
```

And then you could style it using [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) to remove it's borders, make it [`readonly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.readonly) or whatever you need.

There's actually a comparison between different methods displaying sample code [here](http://dadinck.x10.mx/code_example.html).

Answer (score 0):

**This can be done very easily and elegantly *without* special character codes, JavaScript, PHP, <textarea>, or <xmp>.**

Simply wrap the tag's **name** in a `<span>`, which is then wrapped in <>, like so:

`<<span>h1</span>>This text appears to be in a h1 tag but is not formatted as h1.<<span>/h1</span>>`

Which will produce the following when the browser interprets it:

<h1>This text appears to be in a h1 tag but is not formatted as h1.</h1>

<edit>
**However**, It should be noted that different browsers may handle subsequent instances of < and > (such as << or >>) differently, as it is ambiguous to HTML regarding how those cases should be handled. This is why you **should** use special character codes `&lt;` and `&gt;` around your spans instead of literally typing < and >.</edit>

It is also very easy to color operators and method names with in-line CSS this way, which is especially useful if you're writing in a `<code>` block that doesn't automatically implement syntax highlighting for a specific language; a feature of the `<code>` tag I think should be implemented as a property or attribute.