# Print HTML tags in PHP output

Tags: php, html

I have HTML tags present inside php variable. I want to print the values as it is. Here is what i tried.

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

echo htmlentities($str);
// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;

echo $str; //out puts as follows
```

A 'quote' is **bold**

But i want to print it as

```
 A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>
```

Also, Is there any setting can be done at the TOP of the php page, so that i dont need to use it in every php variables ?

Comment: Dont use html ebtities. Just echo $str

Comment: why not just `echo $str`

Comment: If you want to send HTML tags verbatim, don't use `htmlentities()`. If you want to show the tags **in the browser** as literal text, you need to escape it as you are doing currently. Please clarify what you actually want to do

Comment: @Bojangles : I have updated my question to say what i want

Comment: No you haven't. What are you doing with this text? Echoing it to a browser or something else?

Comment: @Bojangles : yes, i am echoing into browser. I thought its understandable that HTML tag output means , browser output .

Comment: Then use `htmlentities()` - the browser will render the escaped character codes as literals so you'll see the raw HTML on the page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use

```
 $str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b> ";

echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

because `htmlentities` convert some characters to HTML entities.

You should instead use [htmlspecialchars](http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

It replaces characters as below:

```
'&' (ampersand) becomes &amp;
'"' (double quote) becomes &quot; when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
"'" (single quote) becomes &#039; only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes &lt;
'>' (greater than) becomes &gt;
```

You can check [php fiddle here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/945-hd8)

Comment: It is printing as `A 'quote' is bold` (bold in bold format). Please read my question

Comment: hey don't downvote Ok. Its you who didn't post the question correctly and then edited it to make sense

Comment: I just edited echo $str output. but my original question says `A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>` is expected output. I did not change that. Still my requirement is `A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>` ; Please edit your answer to accept answer

Comment: echo htmlspecialchars($str); is not outputing anything to browser

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48198/discussion-between-logan-and-shiva)

Comment: htmlspecialchars not working it is converting html tag like <span class="label label-default">No</span> to &lt;span class=&quot;label label-default&quot;&gt;No&lt;/span&gt;

Answer (score 3):

This should work -

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";
echo "<xmp>".$str."</xmp>";
//Outputs - A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>
```

EDIT:

`<XMP>` is deprecated as was pointed out in the comments, and this seems to be the workaround for it(using the `<PRE>` tag and `htmlentities`)-

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";
echo "<pre>".htmlentities($str)."</pre>";
//Outputs - A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>
```

Comment: Great ! it seems, i need to set <xmp> everytime for all variables, Is there any setup done at the begining of the page ?

Comment: It's an html tag. So a good idea would be use a function, taking the parameter as the input string and returning the above echo.

Comment: xmp tag is deprecated check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545/what-was-the-xmp-tag-used-for

Comment: @Shiva : so what is the replacement for that ?

Comment: @Shiva It is old, but it seemed to work for me all the time. Even your thread says so(and it's replacement is debated too). But you are right, it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print HTML, don't use `htmlentities`.

If this is user input, you should still filter it.

Edit:

If you want the browser to show the text as `A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>`, `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` is the correct function to use as they escape the HTML code and the browser will show the tags as you want.

Comment: It is printing as A 'quote' is bold (bold in bold format). Please read my question

Comment: The samething I am explaining. I just edited echo $str output. but my original question says `A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>` is expected output. I did not change that. Still my requirement is `A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>` ; Please edit your answer to accept answer

Comment: `A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>` is printed and is what you've specified.
And then I don't see your problem with htmlentities. This is the output of your code http://jsfiddle.net/t7Kra/

Answer (score -1):

to make it as setting..

```
<?php

function my_custom_echo($str)
{
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
}

my_custom_echo("<p>what ever I want </P>")


?>
```