# Prevent Sql Injection but show posted data as it is on the page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building this application in Codeigniter PHP where i have many forms and grids.

But Issue right now i am facing is very critical regarding security.

When i post data using Ajax, i usually try to get it in controller like this

```
$this->input->post('someInputValueName');
```

but with the above statement anyone can write this below script and that script can be saved in the database as it is.

```
<script type="javascript"> alert('Hello World'); </script>
```

So when that data is shown in page, this above script is not shown as it is, instead it gets executed??

So i tried like this

```
mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('someInputValueName');
```

but with the above mysql method, `\` slashes are added to the `"` and `'`, so this is the final result that is added to database and is shown in pages.

```
<script type=\"javascript\"> alert(\'Hello World\'); </script>
```

Cuz of which in the grid i start getting error, and my grid stopped populating cuz jquery thought it is error.

**Now Coming to my Question**, How is it possible that whatever user writes to input in database that input data should be saved as it is(or anyother way dosent matter) but when that data is called to show on grid or in page it should show as it is and should not be executed or try to execute on page?

Like in facebook comments if i post the above script line, it don't gets executed. it just displays as it is in the comment without any additional slashes.

Comment: Somewhere along the lines you're obviously encoding your input twice. Only escape SQL string prior using it in SQL queries. Better yet, go with the times and use prepared statements / param binding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php

looks like it fits for your needs

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `XMP` tag.
because `XMP` ignores HTML tags and entities
so

```
 <XMP><script type="text/javascript"> alert('Hello World'); </script> aa</XMP>
```

will output exactly what you want.

## Snippet

```html
 <XMP><script type="text/javascript"> alert('Hello World'); </script> aa</XMP>
```

more info about it is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545/what-was-the-xmp-tag-used-for)

**Note** : `code` and `pre` tags won't work for your cause.